# Webpage never finishes loading asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous

Please see the code below:

```
    Public Shared Async Sub AsyncMain()
        Dim a As AsyncronousTest = New AsyncronousTest
        Dim task As Task = a.LoadWebpage()

        Do While 1 = 1
            If a.bool = True Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        MsgBox("test")
    End Sub

Public Class AsyncronousTest

    Public bool As Boolean = False

    Public Sub Callback()
        bool = True
    End Sub

    Public Async Function LoadWebpage() As Task(Of Integer)
        Dim webC As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim newUri As Uri = New Uri("http://webpagetocache")
        Dim task1 As Task = webC.DownloadStringTaskAsync(newUri)
        Await task1
        Callback()
        Return 1
    End Function
End Class
```

`msgbox("test")`  is never reached.  Why?

The purpose of this is to load a webpage overnight so that it can be cached using asp.net.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code using a debugger? Place a breakpoint on the line to see if it's hit, and also check the `Immediate Window` (if you're using Visual Studio) so that no exception is silently thrown.

Comment: does it HAVE to be asynchronous if you are just loading the page? Why not just use a regular non-sync way?

Comment: LoadWebPage is returning an Integer (1), but the return type is Task(Of Integer). the return is perhaps failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `LoadWebPage` and it is returning the task, but this task is never performed, thus the actual code inside `LoadWebPage` is never executed.
You need to perform the task to execute it.

```
Public Async Sub AsyncMain()
    Dim a As AsyncronousTest = New AsyncronousTest
    Dim task As Task(Of Integer) = a.LoadWebpage() ' Here you generate the task

    Dim actualResult = Await task ' Here you perform the task

    Do While 1 = 1
        If a.bool = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    MsgBox("test")
End Sub
```